# Making a minecraft mod in java. Creating and registering an instance

Tags: minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make an uranium ingot that gives players that hold it in their inventory a wither effect. I got some tips from the minecraft forums, they told me to do to make my item give me the wither effect.

> Re: 1.10.2 Item has wither « Reply #2 on: Today at 02:29:58 am » QuoteThank You Create a class that extends Item and overrides
> Item#onUpdate.
>
> In your override, check if the entityIn argument is an instance of EntityLivingBase. If it is, cast it to EntityLivingBase and call EntityLivingBase#isPotionActive to check if it has the MobEffects.WITHER effect active. If it doesn't, create a PotionEffect and call EntityLivingBase#addPotionEffect to add it.

**My Question**

`Create and register an instance of this class instead of Item.`
The last line is what im confused on.
Here is the class i made that he told me to do. Also please inform me if i didnt do something else right in this class

```
package item;

import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.init.MobEffects;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.potion.PotionEffect;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public class UraniumIngotEffect extends Item{


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(ItemStack stack, World worldIn, Entity entityIn,       int       itemSlot, boolean isSelected) {
    if(entityIn instanceof EntityLivingBase){
         Object EntityLivingBase = ((EntityLivingBase)    entityIn).isPotionActive(MobEffects.WITHER);
         
    }else{
        Object PotionEffect =  new PotionEffect(MobEffects.WITHER);
    }


    super.onUpdate(stack, worldIn, entityIn, itemSlot, isSelected);
}

}
```

Comment: Your question is misformatted, and you aren't asking anything. Your post is merely a copy paste of instructions. Please [edit] and be specific about your goals, and what you tried

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the item object in your mod hold the onUpdate method.

This means:

have a class that extends Item(your uranium ingot)

Register the item in the item loader

```
Item myurnanium = new UraniumIngot();
GameRegistry.register(myuranium);
```

and of course make the proper json files so the item will render properly.

I suggest you read:

http://bedrockminer.jimdo.com/modding-tutorials/basic-modding-1-8/first-item/